# Estimation of NO2 Before and After Covid 19 Using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, sentinel-5p

I am working on trend analysis of NO<sub>2</sub> but the chart produced have different minimum and maximum values of tropospheric column number density and, I cannot built a continuous pre, during and lock down chart. Complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/92152c81c76deb7b8242ff5691dfa7cd):

```
var state = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2");

var TN = state.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_CODE',1508));
var chennai= TN.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_CODE',70242));
print(chennai);

Map.addLayer(chennai,['red'],'Chennai');
Map.centerObject(chennai,12);

//count the number of pixel
var image = ee.Image(1).clip(chennai);
var binary = image.eq(1);
var count = binary.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: chennai,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
print(count.get('constant'));

//making collection of points.
var stations=ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(80.1076538,12.9099161),{name:'Alandur Bus Depot  Chennai - CPCB'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(80.26285,13.164544),{name:'Manali  Chennai - CPCB'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(80.2398125,13.0052189),{name:'Velachery Res. Area  Chennai - CPCB'})
  ]);
  
  
//Create the Title label
var title = ui.Label('Tropospheric NO2 column density over Chennai');
title.style().set('position','top-center');
Map.add(title);

  
// //Export the featurecollection to KML
// Export.table.toDrive({
//   collection:stations,
//   description:'exportKML',
//   fileFormat:"KML"
// });

// //Export the featurecollection to CSV
// Export.table.toDrive({
//   collection:stations,
//   description:'exportCSV',
//   fileFormat:"CSV"
// });

//display the points
Map.addLayer(stations,{},'Stations');
Map.centerObject(stations,10);

//prelock down image collection.
var collection_prelock = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2")
.select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-03-30');

//unit conversion from mole to micromole for better numerical analysis.
var mol_to_micromol= collection_prelock.map(function (image) {
  return image.multiply(1000000).set('system:time_start',image.date().millis());
  });
var NO2_pre_lock= mol_to_micromol.mean().clip(chennai) 

// // Define the molar mass of NO2
// var molarMassNO2 = 46.0055;
// var NO2 = collection_prelock.select("tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density");


// // Convert the variable in mole/m^2 to microgram/m^2
// var NO2 = collection_prelock.map(function(image){
//   return image.multiply(molarMassNO2).multiply(1e6);
// });


var band_viz = {opacity:0.55,
min:0, max:0.0002,
palette:['black','blue','cyan','green','green','yellow','red']};

//lock down image collection.
var collection_lock = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2")
.select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
.filterDate('2020-03-01','2020-07-30');

//postlock down image collection.
var collection_postlock = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2")
.select('tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density')
.filterDate('2020-08-01','2020-11-30');


Map.setOptions('hybrid');
Map.addLayer(collection_prelock.max().clip(chennai),band_viz,'S5P NO2 Pre-Lockdown',false);
Map.addLayer(collection_lock.max().clip(chennai),band_viz,'S5P NO2 Lockdown',false);
Map.addLayer(collection_postlock.max().clip(chennai),band_viz,'S5P NO2 Post-Lockdown',false);
Map.style().set('cursor','crosshair');


//mean calculation

var Stat_NO2_prelock= NO2_pre_lock.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry:chennai,
  scale:1000,
  maxPixels:1e9
  });
  print(Stat_NO2_prelock);
  
  //Stadard deviation calculation
  var NO2_stdDev_prelock =NO2_pre_lock.reduceRegion({
  reducer:ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  geometry:chennai,
  scale:1000,
  maxPixels:1e9
  });
  print(NO2_stdDev_prelock );
  
  var timeSeries = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: mol_to_micromol,
  region: chennai,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'NO2 Time Series',
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Day of the year',
    titleTextStyle:{italic:false,bold:true}
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'NO2 (micro mole)',
    titleTextStyle:{italic:false,bold:true} 
  },
  lineWidth:2,
  colors:['39a8a7','grey']
});

print(timeSeries);

//A chart for pixels and their association NO2 density, printed it to the console
var Pixel_NO2_density =
       ui.Chart.image.histogram({image:NO2_pre_lock,
         region: chennai,
         scale: 1000,
       })
       .setOptions({
         title:'Tropospheric_NO2_density_Histogram',
         hAxis: {
           title:'NO2 density',
             titleTextStyle:{italic:false,bold:true}
          },
        vAxis: {
        title: 'No.of pixels',
        titleTextStyle:{italic:false,bold:true}},
        colors: ['cf513e','1d6b99','f0af07']
        });
print(Pixel_NO2_density);

//display of colorbar and data filtered data
function ColorBar(palette){
  return ui.Thumbnail({
    image: ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0),
    params: {
      bbox: [0,60,250,300],
      dimensions: 'png',
      min:0,
      max:300,
      palette:['black','blue','purple','cyan','green','yellow','red'],
      },
      style:{stretch:'horizontal',margin: '1px 2px'},
      });
}

function makeLegend(low,mid,high,palette) {
  var labelPanel =ui.Panel(
    [
      ui.Label(low,{margin:'8px 10px'}),
      ui.Label(mid,{margin:'8px 10px', textAlign : 'center', stretch: 'horizontal'}),
      ui.Label(high,{margin:'8px 10px'}),
      ],
      ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'));
    return ui.Panel([ColorBar(palette),labelPanel]);
}

Map.add(makeLegend(0,150,300,['black','blue','purple','cyan','green','yellow','red']));
var button = ui.Button('2020 JAN-MAR');
Map.add(button);



  
  //a time series is created forfiltered date and printed it to the cosole
  var time_series = ui.Chart.image
  .doySeriesByYear({
    imageCollection: mol_to_micromol,
    bandName : 'tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density',
    region: chennai,
    regionReducer : ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 1000,
    sameDayReducer : ee.Reducer.mean(),
    
  })
  .setOptions({
    interpolateNulls : true,
    title: 'Average tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density Value by Day of Year_pre_lock',
    hAxis: {
      title:'Day of year',
             titleTextStyle:{italic:false,bold:true}
          },
        vAxis: {
        title: 'tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density',
        titleTextStyle:{italic:false,bold:true}
         },
         lineWidth: 2,
        colors: ['39a8a7','9c4f97']
        });
  print(time_series);


var lockdown_max=collection_lock.max();

Export.image.toDrive({
  image:collection_lock.max(),
  description: 'Max_No2 Lockdown',
  scale:1500,
  region:chennai
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with your obtained results? Last chart image is continuous.